# Does MATLAB create c++ files during converting .m file(s) to a shared library?

Tags: matlab, shared-libraries

I can create a shared library a my .m file by using **deploytool** in matlab. But now I need .cpp sources from this .m file. I know that I can use **Matlab coder**. But as an alternative solution Can I get c++ source files that are generated by matlab during creating c++ shared library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying you MATLAB code to a shared library, MATLAB Compiler archives and encrypts your MATLAB code and creates a small wrapper library (or executable) file. When the the library (or executable) is run, it dearchives and decrypts your MATLAB code and runs it against the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR).

It does not convert your MATLAB code to either C or C++, so you can't retrieve any C++ source code.

MATLAB Coder converts a subset of the MATLAB language into C code. It does not produce C++ code.